# performSegueWithIdentifier causes fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift2, segue

What I need was to detect which cell was selected on my tableView, and using the `indexPath.row` to get the index of my object array which is `personList`, and pass that data to another View Controller and print on the label.

However, I received an error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Below are my codes.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    selectedCell = indexPath.row
    performSegueWithIdentifier("DetailScreen", sender: nil)
}

override func performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) {
    //detailedView.personName = personList[selectedCell].GetPersonName()
    detailedView.LastNameLabel.text = personList[selectedCell].GetLastName()
}
```

Comment: What is detailedView?

Comment: `var detailedView = PersonDetailScreen()` It is my second view controller that displays the data. I declared this at class level.

Comment: See my answer. You are doing it totally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you initialize the detailedView in the wrong way. Do it like this:

```
 // IMPORTANT: Override prepareForSegue for your purpose, not performSegueWithIdentifier
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "DetailScreen" {
         // Do the initialization here. You don't need a global variable.
         if let detailedView = segue.destinationViewController as? PersonDetailScreen {
             //detailedView.personName = personList[selectedCell].GetPersonName()
             detailedView.LastNameLabel.text = personList[selectedCell].GetLastName()
         }
     }   
}
```

PS: You are overriding the wrong function.

**EDIT**

As mentioned in your comment `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `prepareForSegue` doesn't coexist because the method you used for creating the segue is wrong. And with that, your code is doing more wrong than doing the right thing. Right now you might have created the segue by control dragging starting from the `UITableView` prototype cell to the destination view controller. Now when you do this what happens is, you are telling that the segue must be performed on the clicking on that particular cell itself, which means you are setting its action right in the storyboard. So even if you don't implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, your code will still navigate to the second `ViewController` when the cell is clicked. But your requirement is that you must do some custom operations when the cell is clicked and then navigate to the second viewcontroller. For doing that, delete the current segue and then create a new segue with the same identifier like the way you create a normal segue - by control dragging from the source ViewContoller(not the tableview cell prototype) to the destination view controller. Then replace the `override func performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?)` function with the function I have provided in my original answer and then your code will work smooth.

PS: Make sure your Identifier is named correctly.

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<PersonDisplay.FirstViewController: 0x7feabaec2870>) has no segue with identifier 'DetailScreen''
```

This happens since you haven't set the name for the segue correctly in the storyboard. So rectify that as well. Specify the identifier for the segue in the storyboard.

Comment: there can't be `prepareForSegue` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to co-exists. It will run `prepareForSegue` and thereby I can't detect which is the selected row.

Comment: Did you try it? All you need to do is to replace your performSegueWithIdentifier function with my code and remove the global declaration of detailedView. Your code will run smoothly as required.

Comment: You don't need to make any changes in didSelectRow.

Comment: Yes. That was my initial code before coming here to post my question. If you do a search, you notice that other developers also ask why `prepareForSegue` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` doesn't co-exist. They recommended using `performSegueWithIdentifier` instead.

Comment: You might have understood it wrong. It is not that `didSelectRow` and `prepareForSegue` doesn't coexist. the problem is the way you created the segue. You might have created the segue by control dragging from the tableviewcell, which will directly trigger an action when tableviewcell is clicked. What you need to do is, create the segue by control dragging from the ViewController itself like you create a normal segue and then use the identifier. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Apologies, you might be correct. I tried your codes, so it went to `prepareForSegue` and check for `if segue.identifier == "DetailScreen" and it does not fulfil criteria. The code then continue to run and goes to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. However when it runs `performSegueWithIdentifier("DetailScreen", sender: nil)` I get 


  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<PersonDisplay.FirstViewController: 0x7feabaec2870>) has no segue with identifier 'DetailScreen''

Comment: See my updated answer. That issue might be with your storyboard, not with the code. :-)

Comment: Yes what you are assuming is what I require. I got what you meant. After changing the segue and replace my codes with yours, it now invokes `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` first, instead of invoking `prepareForSegue`, which is the wrong way. However my app still doesn't run with an error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<PersonDisplay.FirstViewController: 0x7feabaec2870>) has no segue with identifier 'DetailScreen''`

Comment: Just set the Segue identifier in the storyboard to "DetailScreen"(Without the double quotes), and your problem is solved. :-)

Comment: Saw your edited answer, and it worked like charm!! thanks so much! Sorry for being ignorant!!

Answer (score 1):

You should pass valuable to detailedView and assign to label in viewDidLoad:

```
detailedView.lastName = personList[selectedCell].GetLastName()
```

Go viewDidload of detailedView:

```
 detailedView.LastNameLabel.text = detailedView.lastName
```

Comment: Yes I've tried this, however, on my second view controller, however in the viewDidLoad, it re-instantiate my `lastname` variable again, which will be "".

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. When you create instance for last name, it just hold value, why re-instaintiate?

Comment: SecondViewController is not loaded for the first time. When my codes run, it loads the FirstViewController. When I select a particular cell, it will then run SecondViewController. So at the swift coding, when it runs `detailedView.lastName = personList[selectedCell].GetLastName()`, it does store the variable. But when it displays the SecondViewController, it re-instantiate the `lastName` again to ""

Comment: You should override function prepareforsegue like answer above.

Comment: Hi, I tried above codes, but I got an error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<PersonDisplay.FirstViewController: 0x7feabaec2870>) has no segue with identifier 'DetailScreen'' " when running `performSegueWithIdentifier("DetailScreen", sender: nil)`

Comment: if you got this error. I think you don't drage segue from firstcontroller to seconcontroller have identifier: DetailScreen.